# Can't add hair to a rigfy'd body

Tags: objects, add-on, bones, hair

So hey! What's good?
I just recently made my first attempt on hair (as an OBJECT I mean, you can see it in the picture) and I wanted to add it to my female model who's also working properly with the rigfy addon. Thing is...I can't seem to make the hair stick to the head haha so, basically, everything works, animation is perfect, but my poor lil char is still bald for some reason I can't figure out. Tried parenting, snapping bones to the original rig, weight painting, even making the whole hair again just to make sure I wasn't skipping any points and still..NOTHING. Moreover, I don't think there's a way to parent the loops from rigfy directly into the hair, which makes it worse. Please help this poor fella who can do nothing in Blender but *cry*.

[image]

Comment: Did you parent the hair object to the head bone? PS: please not so much emotion.

Comment: Yeah, in actuallity it was the first thing I did! It must be something about this add-on that I don't understand...thanks anyway! PS: Oh I forgot about that, you're right: straight to the point, unsensitive robot mode activated